# PDF checkboxes with iTextsharp

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I've an Android app that needs to generate a PDF document with various data fetched from a database. Everything is working fine, included tables and checkboxes, that I generate with this snipped of code :

```
    private PdfFormField WriteCheckbox(ref PdfContentByte pcb, float xPos, float yPos, string fldName, bool cbState)
    {
        yPos = yPos - 2f;
        float cbDist = 1f;
        Rectangle cbRect = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, xPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_SIZE, yPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_SIZE);
        RadioCheckField checkbox = new RadioCheckField(pcb.PdfWriter, cbRect, "", "");
        checkbox.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_SQUARE;
        checkbox.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
        checkbox.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID;
        checkbox.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
        checkbox.FieldName = fldName;

        if(cbState)
        {
            pcb.SetLineWidth(1.2f);
            pcb.MoveTo(xPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_DISTANCE, yPos + cbDist);
            pcb.LineTo(xPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_SIZE - cbDist - 1, yPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_SIZE - cbDist - 1);
            pcb.MoveTo(xPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_SIZE - cbDist - 1, yPos + cbDist);
            pcb.LineTo(xPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_DISTANCE, yPos + DEFAULT_CHECKBOX_SIZE - cbDist - 1);
        }

        pcb.Stroke();

        return(checkbox.RadioField);
    }
```

The resulting PDF is visualize correctly on the tablet (Nexus 7), but when I copy it con my PC and open if with Acrobat Reader all is at the correct place except the squares I draw to show the checkboxes. I can se the cross I draw inside the squares, but not the surrounding square. What is happening ?

This is the link to the pdf generated :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p388bw7egjsbi80/curit_2015_2.pdf?dl=0

This is the link to the Nexus 7 screenshot showing the very same file :
[image]

Any hint would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your tags are wrong. iTextSharp is for C#. I think you meant iText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the squares I draw to show the checkboxes

Your code doesn't draw any squares.

What your code does, actually is surprising,

- it creates numerous checkbox AcroForm form fields, none of them checked, none of them named, with a square visualization selection, and
- it draws a cross in the page content in positions you seem to want to have appear checked.

So even if the created PDF was valid, it could irritate people, as they apparently could not de-select the pre-selected entries, merely select them a second time resulting in two overlapping crosses.

---

The reason why your checkbox borders only appear on some PDF viewers and not on others, is the same as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35646955/1729265) to the question ["iText - Java Android - Adding fields to existing pdf"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35630320/1729265):

**AcroForm form fields need to have a non-empty name.** AcroForm forms contents are meant to be sent to some service for automatic evaluation, so they must be named and they must be distinguishable by their respective names.

Some PDF viewers recognize early that they couldn't properly handle fields with empty names and, therefore, don't even show them while other viewers recognize that later when trying to save or post the form, or don't recognize it at all, producing broken outputs.

---

But even after naming the boxes individually, you should decide whether you want to have AcroForm form fields or not. In the former case you would merely add properly named form fields and set them selected or not, and in the latter case you would draw complete checkbox appearances (not merely the check marks) in the page content and not use form fields at all.

Comment: I didn't realize that the simplest solution was to draw the checkbox myself. Actually I don't need the users to interact with the document, because it's only a preview of the final document (a report control for thermal generators). Having PDF the ability to put directly a CheckBox object on the doc, it seemed to me the most obvious solution, and so I searched around for any hint, and found some AcroForm samples for doing it. @amedee, the tags report c# and iTextSharp because (sorry for not mentioning it) I'm working with Xamarin.